# How to send post request from inside docker container?

Tags: python, docker

I am attempting to send a post request from inside a docker container from a server. The container runs fine up until it attempts to make the post request at which point it just hangs.

The server has internet connectivity which has been tested via ping command.

This is the code at which it hangs

```
while not send_flag:
        print('Attempting to send post')
        r = requests.post(
            'https://notarealaddress.fake', 
            headers = header,
            data = json.dumps(payload))
        if r.json()["status"] == 'success':
            print('Successfully Pushed')
            send_flag = True
        else:
            print('Failed to send alert with response:\n {}'.format(r.json()))
            sleep(60)
```

I cannot see any of the latter print statements after 'Attempting to send post', on force quitting the program the error received is:

```
  File "./main.py", line 16, in <module>
    send_incident(payload)
File "/usr/src/app/pagerduty_functions.py", line 50, in send_incident
data = json.dumps(payload))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
(self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
```

The Docker images runs successfully when run from my local machine so i'm finding it hard to identify the problem.

Comment: That just tells you *where* the error occurred; you left out what the actual error *is*.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the container itself has network connectivity?  You should 'exec' into your container and then see if you can get out to the internet.  You might have to install 'telnet' or 'curl' if you don't already have those in the container. - It sounds to me like your container can't get out to the internet.  If that's the case, then the problem is in your Docker configuration, not your code. - In fact, if the same container runs fine on your local machine, then by definition the problem is in the way your docker host is set up.

Comment: I have entered into the container and run 'ping google.com', that seems to be working fine

Comment: so inside the container using bash to run 'ping google.com' shows a connection. If i run a python terminal inside the container and try to pull a webpage using `page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')' (import done) then it hangs as it does in the python script

Answer (score -2):

Whatever image you run, you need to check ip and domain name connectivity of your container by following method first.

You can replace your domain name below.

```
sudo docker run -it python ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.160.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tsa01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=2.53 ms
64 bytes from tsa01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.68): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=2.59 ms
64 bytes from tsa01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.68): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=2.65 ms
64 bytes from tsa01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.68): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=2.59 ms
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but this is not an answer to the question.  This is a debugging step that might help the OP to arrive at an answer.  This belongs in the comments, at least until it can become part of a complete answer to the question.